# Why is my union's size bigger than I expected?

Tags: c++, unions

When I print the size of a union like this:

```
union u {
  char c[5];
  int i;
} un;
```

using this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("size of union = %d ",sizeof(un));
    return 0;
}
```

I get an answer of 8 using Visual C++, but I expected 5. Why?

Well, for the same example,
i did something like this:

```
int i1 = 0x98761234;
un.i = i1;
printf("\n un.c[0] = %x ",un.c[0]);
printf("\n un.c[1] = %x ",un.c[1]);
printf("\n un.c[2]= %x ",un.c[2]);
printf("\n un.c[3] = %x ",un.c[3]);
printf("\n un.c[4] = %x ",un.c[4]);
printf("size of union = %d ",sizeof(un));
```

i got results like

```
un.c[0] = 34;
un.c[1] = 12;
un.c[2] = 76;
un.c[3] = ffffff98;
```

why are there 6fs at un.c[3]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator produces the size of a variable or type, *including* any padding necessary to separate elements in an array of that type such that everything is still correctly aligned. Since your union has an `int` member, it needs to be 4-byte aligned, so its "natural" size gets rounded upwards to the next multiple of 4 bytes.

---

The `ffffff98` is because you're compiling with signed `char`. Using `%x` with an argument that is not `unsigned int` causes undefined behaviour; what you're seeing is sometimes called *sign-extension*. The result of your aliasing is `0x98` reinterpreted as `char`, which is `-104`. This retains its value on being promoted to `int` (this is called the *default argument promotions*), and the int `-104` when aliased as `unsigned int` becomes `0xffffff98`.

Answer (score 3):

The alignment of your union must be the largest alignment of any of its members. This is 4. Therefore, the size of the union must be aligned to that size. It could have been 5 (as `c` is the largest member of the union), but because the alignment of the union as a whole is 4, the size of the union is padded to 8.

Note that this is just for VC++. The standard does not specifically require it. Though it does allow implementations to pad types as needed, which VC++ does. GCC could do something different, and there could be compile-time switches you could employ to change this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Compiler adds few bytes for alignment

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can add padding wherever it wants to structs, unions, and classes to speed memory accesses. You are seeing the effect of that. For Visual C++, the padding is usually a multiple of the size of the largest member type. In this instance, the largest member is an int, therefore it pads the union with 3 unused bytes to make the total size 8.

Comment: Assuming 4-byte integers, the largest member is c, which is 5 bytes. The compiler rounds this up to 8 by adding padding. If the system is using 8-byte integers, then 8 is used for the union size.

Comment: @Brian I changed my answer shortly before you commented to "largest member type", to more clearly indicate an int.

Comment: I dunno, I still don't think your answer is clear or correct. You say the largest member is an int, but it isn't. It is an array of 5 chars. Since 5 > 4 it rounds up to the next multiple of the native word size, which makes it 8.

Comment: Well maybe we are saying the same thing, just slightly differently after all.

Comment: @Brian well take this for example: `union { char[9]; double d; };` on MSVC++, the size is 16. When I say "largest member type" I mean the largest type that considers arrays by the elements that are in them. Because `char` is a base type but `char[5]` is kind of a "compound type."

Comment: I see what you're saying but I agree that it's unclear and slightly misleading the way it's phrased

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I tried this with a lots of examples and looks that
 union size is equivalent to 
(size of max element)+ padding(depending upon the size of highest datatype used).