# Why does GCC allocate separate stack space for local unions in different scopes?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, stack-size

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef TRY
#define TRY struct
#endif

TRY testme
{
  int one;
  int two;
  char three;
  int four;
};

int
main (void)
{
  {
    volatile TRY testme one;

    one.one = 2;
    one.three = 7;
  }

  {
    volatile TRY testme twos;

    twos.one = 3;
  }

  {
    volatile TRY testme one;

    one.one = 4;
  }

  {
    volatile TRY testme twos;

    twos.one = 5;
  }

  {
    volatile TRY testme twos;

    twos.one = 6;
  }

  {
    volatile TRY testme twos;

    twos.one = 6;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled as is for x86 is (meaning testme is a struct), the stack size the compiler allocates for main is 16 bytes.

```
$ gcc -g -O2 test.c -o test 
$ objdump -d ./test | ./checkstack.pl i386 | grep main
16 main
```

However, compiled with TRY defined to union (meaning testme is a union), the stack size the compiler allocates for main is 32 bytes:

```
$ gcc -DTRY=union -g -O2 test.c -o test 
$ objdump -d ./test | ./checkstack.pl i386 | grep main
```

Moreover, any additional instances of the struct/union defined in additional scopes, will produce bigger stack allocations when using a union, but will not enlarge the stack allocation when  used as a struct.

Now, this does not make sense - the union should take less stack space, if at all, not more, then a struct with the same fields!

It seems as if GCC treats unions as used concurrently even when in different scopes, but does not do the same for structs.

Some more clarifications:

1. volatile is used to stop the compiler from optimizing away the assignments. Loosing the volatile and compiling with no optimization produces the same results.
2. Even if testme is a struct that has a union as one of the members, the same behavior is observed. In  other words - it is enough that one of the members of a struct is a union for GCC to for separate stack allocations.
3. Compiler is gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) but other GCC versions for other architectures showed the same behavior.
4. checkstack.pl simply searches the objdump output for the instructions used to allocate stack (sub to the stack pointer).

My question:

1. Why does GCC do this? is this a bug or is there a reason for this behavior?
2. Assuming this is not a bug, is a there a way to work around this and force GCC to allocate stack for stucts same as unions.

**Clarification**: My question is not why the struct or union appears to be bigger in size from the size of its part. I understand the reason is padding for alignment. My problem is that the compiler allocates multiple stack frames for different instances of the union even though they are defined in different scopes while it shouldn't and indeed doesn't do the same for a struct with the same fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe unions aren't as well optimized at `-O2` (yet)? Have a look at the generated assembler code. Also try disabling `strict-aliasing`. Oh, and try a current GCC.

Comment: Have you taken a lookt at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453881/sizeof-union-larger-than-expected-how-does-type-alignment-take-place-here) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212585/why-is-my-unions-size-bigger-than-i-expected) ? It seems to be a matter of padding and alignment constraints

Comment: @Anony-Mousse -fno-strict-aliasing produces the same results. I'm building latest GCC to test.

Comment: @Coren I have, thanks. My question is not why the size of the structure is bigger then the sum of its part. It is why GCC allocates different stack areas for different instances of the union in different  when it doesn't do the same for the struct

Comment: If you do a single block only, how much stack is then allocated? In any case, it should recognize it can reuse the stack memory at the end of each block. The only reason I can imagine the compile choses not to, is so it can initialize it once for all. so 6*16 bytes -> reuse the 16 bytes each time, 6*4 bytes -> init once, keep 6 instances on the stack since they are so tiny. At 4 bytes, stack management probably is more expensive than keeping the extra 4 bytes each for this program.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse for structs it is the same for a single block or any number of multiple ones - 16 bytes in this specific setup. For union, the amount grows with the number of blocks. Put 20 blocks get 200 bytes stack etc.

Comment: What is the value for a single block?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse for x86 it is 16 bytes for a single block in both struct and union form. I also tried gcc 4.6.3-prerelase (that is the latest pre-relase of the stable version of GCC) - same results.

Comment: Optimizing code for modern hardware sometimes requires that things be done out of sequence.  From what I've read, gcc sometimes needs to allocate local variables with non-overlapping usage separately in order to allow for the possibility of out-of-order execution.  It might make sense for gcc to start by allocating the variables separately, then applying the optimizations, and then consolidating variables whose usage still doesn't overlap even after optimizations have been applied, but I don't know whether any such logic has ever been added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently at least an attempt has been made to relax gcc's strict aliasing paranoia regarding unions.

You may wish to make sure that gcc source you compile from has this or equivalent patch applied:
http://codereview.appspot.com/4444051/

Answer (score -1):

It's looks like mater of padding and basic default size definition of the Int.

In 32 bit the memory map will be:
One (2 bytes)
Two (2 bytes)
Three (1 byte)
(1 bytes) padding 
four (2 bytes)

Total - 8 bytes.

in 64 bit it will be:
One (4 bytes)
Two (4 bytes) 
Three (1 byte)
(3 bytes padding)
Four (4 bytes)

Total - 16 bytes.

If you change the "int" to "short int", the memory will look different.

Comment: But as a `union`, the whole thing should only take 4 bytes, no matter if it's 32 or 64bit.

Comment: I have no problem with how much a single struct or union takes. My problem is that GCC seems to allocate different stack space for different instances of the union defined in different scopes, even though it need not do that and indeed doesn't do that for struct

Comment: Even as a union it's depend on what comes next.  if it's inside array of the union - it will take the 32 bit even under 64 bit.  if it's variable, then on 64 bit systems it will be padded to 64 bits.  It's not the scope, it's "what comes next".